# Idiomatic expressions for falsity pt. 2: the sophist falsity - Translation of Spanish: ‘versear’ or ‘chamuyar’

Tags: idioms, slang, idiom-requests, translation, spanish

**Introduction**

According to correspondence theory, if you say or think something that does not correspond to reality then you have said something that is false. While this is an obvious concept learned in childhood, and while is true that we say many things that are false, we seldom say that ‘something is false’ — at least in Spanish. Instead, we distinguish between different types of falsities and use the idiomatic expression most appropriate to the situation.

**The sophist falsity**

If somebody say things that consist about fallacious arguments, sophisms or false statements with the objective of gaining reputation or prestige we may say either that he *chamuyó* or *verseó*; or that he is a *chamuyero*, *versero* (the correspodent adjectives). The former comes from caló *chamullar* while the latter comes from *verso* (verse, because of the idea that often a verse can be sweet to the ear but with a false content).

What English **idiomatic** or **slang words** fit best for the description I gave?

- Be careful because the words sometimes could be used with the meaning of *seduce* or *charming* which often have a positive connotation. I think a lot of terms which fall into this category: *sweet-talker*, *enchanter*, *delighter*, etc. But the most usual sense is negative.
- The words could be confused with an *adulation*. But this one focuses on the listener, while *chamuyar* focuses on the speaker. The idea behind the word is not that you are ‘specifically and constantly’ interested in someone, but that you are under pressure (e.g. an exam or a presentation) and you utter a nice discourse in order to (try to) show that you know what you are asked for. I found: *flattering*,  *charm the pants off*, *licker*. But I think these terms are synonyms of *adulate*.

Example #1:

> A: —How would you explain that a diode performs poorly at higher frequencies? What happens? 
> B: —The diffusion capacitance predominates. [Thinking that because he used the term *difussion capacitance* then A will be convinced that the answer is good] 
> A: —That's *chamuyo / verso*. I'm not asking how can you model a diode, but *what* represents the capacitance in the model of the diode that was given in the lecture.

Maybe ‘that's *bullshit*’ could be used, but this word is much more aggressive.

Example #2:

> A: —I can't believe that X got his project approved by the committee. The stats and numbers he presented are nonsense.
> B: —What a *chamuyero*/*versero* he is! [said as a complain]

Comment: Do you mean that "bullshit" is more aggressive, or that "chamuyo/verso" is more aggressive?

Comment: You need to ask a philosopher or translator specifying in philosophy how this is usually translated/expressed rather than making up your own translations.

Comment: @alphabet *bullshit* is more aggressive

Comment: @StuartF Philosophers don't use this term, I'm asking how would you say it 'in the street'

Comment: Is there a policy here that questions can be closed as duplicates if answers (broadly) correspond? This seems to go against regular SE guidelines.

Comment: @Joachim At last, a reasonable remark about CVing...

Comment: If ***bullshit*** is too coarse, and exclamations like ***Nonsense**!* and ***Poppycock**!* are too demeaningly "affected", maybe ***disingenuous*** would fit. Much depends on the speaker's opinion as to ***why*** someone has just said something that's highly questionable, and the relative social status of the conversants.

Comment: Real Academia dictionary: chamuyo
1. m. coloq. Arg. y Ur. Palabrería que tiene el propósito de impresionar o convencer. Coloquial, Argentina and Uruguay, verbiage aimed at impressing or convincing.

Comment: By using terms like sophist and falsity  you make this sound much more lahdeedah than it is.

Comment: @Lambie I don't agree. Actually, if you know for what the sophists were accused for, then you only need a slang for a person who does the same (just like a sophist). And the definition you provided is not enough accurate, I don't care what the RAE says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is no single word or expression that fits all contexts and your examples. *Deceive* is a common and general verb (and *deception* for the noun) that covers the definition, but it is not slang and it won't work in every situation.

> **deceive** *verb* 
> deliberately cause (someone) to believe something that is not true, especially for personal gain.
>
> *Google Dictionary*

For your first example, *bullshit* works as a slang word; but if it is too vulgar (as you've mentioned also), you could use ***nonsense***.

> That's *nonsense*. I'm not asking how can you model a diode, but what represents the capacitance in the model of the diode that was given in the lecture.

or you could start with saying "**Don't fool me!**". *To fool someone* is slang for *to trick* or *deceive (someone)*.

For your second example, ***con artist*** works as a slang word.

> What a *con-artist* he is!

> **con artist** 
> *noun* INFORMAL 
> a person who cheats or tricks others by persuading them to believe something that is not true.
>
> *Google Dictionary*

Note: As you've mentioned also, in some contexts, *chamuyar* is used for *to flatter*, *to charm*, *to sweet-talk*, *to butter up* etc.; but you wanted to get away from that connotation and focus on the sense "deception with false statements".

Comment: con artist is the wrong word for the Spanish.

Comment: @Lambie I wouldn't say just "wrong" brusquely. There are details in the answer. _Bullshit_ and its variants are vulgar slang. Even the OP mentioned that _bullshit_ is too strong. _Chamuyar_ is not vulgar slang also. It is about equivalency and there are different usages, not about exact translation.

Comment: chamuyar is not con. verbiage aimed at impressing or convincing. , translated from the RAE dictionary, link above. Bullshit may be too strong for the OP; not for  me. :) Translation is about equivalent meaning, not equivalency. One translates meaning. Of course, nothing is 100% the same in the other language. The RAE does say colloquial.

Comment: @Lambie **con artist** is a good equivalent it works only as  an adjective but it's ok

Comment: @tac Do you mean _chamuyero_ (and _versero_) only works as an adjective? _Con artist_ is a noun and your second example requires a noun. Equivalency between languages is not always exact; even in terms of parts of speech; and especially with colloquialisms. However, you can still find some adjective equivalents in English, like _slick_ or _sleek_ which could work in some contexts.

Comment: @ermanen NO, they can be adjectives or verbs. *Con artist* only works as an adjective because *conning* doesn't exist. Nevertheless, it's a good candidate for translating

Comment: @tac I think you are mixing up some terms. _Con artist_ is a noun; and it is in the definition also. The blank in your second example requires a noun, so I've offered a noun. _Chamuyero_ is the adjective form of the verb _chamuyar_; but _chamuyero_ can be used as a noun also. https://deleahora.com/diccionario/chamuyero

Comment: @ermanen there always've been an ambivalence between nouns and adjectives. Just like in programming, there is an ambivalence between pointers and arrays.

Answer (score 1):

In American English, possibly other dialects as well, someone who is able to convince people using facile arguments and perhaps some flashy charts and graphs, with a bit of charm thrown in, can be called a **bullshit artist**.

> What a bullshit artist he is!

It's somewhat harsher than "con-artist".

Comment: bullshit artist is good but con artist is not good here. Or even bullshitter.

Comment: @Lambie: Say why.  I'm suggesting it for "What a ________ he is!"