# Idiomatic expressions for falsity pt. 3: the guesser falsity - Translation of Spanish: ‘mandar fruta’

Tags: slang, idiom-requests, translation, spanish

**Introduction**

According to correspondence theory, if you say or think something that does not correspond to reality then you have said something that is false. While this is an obvious concept learned in childhood, and while is true that we say many things that are false, we seldom say that ‘something is false’ — at least in Spanish. Instead, we distinguish between different types of falsities and use the idiomatic expression most appropriate to the situation.

**The guesser falsity**

This is similar to what I asked in the [previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/613277/idiomatic-expressions-for-falsity-pt-2-the-sophist-falsity-translation-of-sp). It's a deliberately-made falsity*, but with the subtle difference that it's not planified at all. Out of the blue, you are asked for some information and you answer guessing and giving the impression that you know what you were asked for. It's **usually used in exams**, as can be seen in these two examples:

> No sabía la respuesta a la pregunta, así que le **mandé fruta**.

> I didn't know the answer to the question, so I ‘**guessed**’.

> — ¿Cómo te fue en el examen? 
> —  Ni idea. No creo haber aprobado. **Mandé fruta** en casi todo.

> — How did you do in the exam? 
> — I don't know. I don't think I'll pass. I ‘**guessed**’ almost everything.

If I had to tell the difference between this expression and *chamuyar*, I would say that the *fruta* is less elaborated, more incoherent and less credible than a *chamuyo*. If you google the expression, there's a lot of sites that will say that is a synonym of the latter. Often you can replace one term for another; but what is missing in those descriptions is that nuance of insecurity and doubt present in the one who ‘invents the story’. Are there slang expressions or idioms in English that capture this very sense of *guessing*? I only found *to take a stab at*, but not sure how and in which contexts it's used.

---

*: Of course that if you *mandás fruta* (guess), you can *pegarle* (succeed) or *errarle* (miss). But if you didn't study for an exam, 99% of the times you fail. So we could consider this expression as part of the falsities, although strictly is not one of them.

Comment: You rioplantense speakers sure have a million delightful expressions! In case others want more details I found this reference: [*¿Qué significa la expresión “Mandar Fruta”? Se usa para decir que alguien dice cualquier cosa, cosas sin sentido o razón, estupideces, inventos, chamuyos. Cuando alguien habla de algo que no sabe, no conoce, no entiende pretendiendo que sabe, conoce y entiende.*](http://portenisima.com.ar/notadetalle.php?notaid=120) And [here's another one](https://www.significadode.org/mandar%20fruta.htm).

Comment: Doesn't *guess* always have an element of insecurity and doubt and uncertainty? If you wanted to be more certain you'd use a word like *estimate* or *improvise* or *answer off the top of my head*.

Comment: @StuartF You don't catch the expression intuitively. Will be useless to explain, but no. *Tirar fruta* or *mandar fruta* is not the same than *doing an estimation*. *Improvising* is too serious and is usually used in other contexts. I'm looking for slangs

Comment: @tac In English, the word *slang* is not a count-noun. But you can use it as an attributive noun modifying a plural noun, as in *I'm looking for some slang expressions.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom (***take) a shot in the dark*** can be used for a wild guess and it is a good fit for your example about answering questions in an exam. The Free Dictionary citing Farlex has the definition below including a very similar example to yours:

> **take a shot in the dark** 
> To make a guess or estimate with very little or no assurance as to its accuracy.
>
> *I had absolutely no idea what the answer was for the last question on the exam, so I just took a shot in the dark and hoped for the best.*
>
> <sub>Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. S.v. "take a shot in the dark." Retrieved October 8 2023 from https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+a+shot+in+the+dark</sub>

***Wing it*** is another idiom that works, especially when you are talking about exams, tests etc.

> — How did you do in the exam? 
> — I don't know. I just **winged it**.

> **wing it** 
> To do or attempt something with little preparation in advance; to improvise.
>
> *Oh man, I totally forgot that I'm supposed to do this presentation today—I'll just have to wing it.*
>
> <sub>wing it. (n.d.) Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. (2015). Retrieved October 8 2023 from https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wing+it</sub>

Note: If you want a general verb, ***make (something) up*** is a good equivalent as a common phrasal verb that can work in many contexts. It is usually used in the sense to invent, fabricate (a story, lie, word, fictional scene/character,  etc.).

> I didn't know the answer, so I just made it up.